# How do you replace the elements of an array with elements from another array?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to replace specific elements in the array fre_index with specific elements in the array qn_red. This is my code.

```
index = []
freq = [201001, 201002, 201003, 201004,201005, 201006, 201007, 201008, 201009, 201010, 
201011, 201012,201013, 201014, 201015, 201016]
freq_red = [201001.3, 201009.4, 201012.5]
qn_red = ['v', 'n', 'c']
for j in range(len(freq_red)):
    for i in range(len(freq)-1):
        if freq[i] <= freq_red[j] <= freq[i+1]:
            index.append(i)
fre_index = np.arange(len(freq))
for j in range(len(index)-1):
    for n, i in enumerate(fre_index):
        if i == index[j]:
            fre_index[n] = qn_red[j]
```

However, I get an error:

```
    fre_index[n] = qn_red[j]
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'v'
```

If I write

```
fre_index[n] = 34
```

instead of

```
fre_index[n] = qn_red[j]
```

the code runs without an error.

Thanks to a comment below I now know that this is because I am trying to mix strings and integers in the same array.

The output I want is an array, fre_index, where it is the same length as the array freq with only some of the elements containing strings from the array qn_red.

Could you tell me how to make such an array?

Comment: provide your expected output

Comment: qn_red contains only strings, whereas fre_index should contain only integers. What do you expect `fre_index[n] = qn_red[j]` to do?

Comment: `fre_index` is a numpy array. You cannot mix types (in this case, numbers and strings) in the same column of a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I have realised the solution is to make a new variable

```
fre_index_str = ['']*len(fre_index)
```

and then do

```
fre_index_str[n] = qn_red[j]
```